# Using mySQL to create a booking summary - joining multiple tables , calculating multiple fields

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to create a table the shows a booking summary for a rafting business.  The EER diagram shows how everything is related.  I am struggling with how to show only 1 row per trip (i am returning multiple rows and the numbers are multiplied).  Here is my code so far.

```
use www;

 SELECT 
    d.destination_name,
    tt.trip_type_name,
    t.trip_number,
    t.trip_date,
    (e.first_name + e.last_name) AS guide_name,
    t.trip_capacity,
    COUNT(r.guest_id) AS guests_booked,
    (COUNT(r.guest_id)-t.trip_capacity) AS positions_available
FROM
    employees e,
    destination d,
    trip_type tt,
    trips t,
    reservation r
GROUP BY d.destination_name , tt.trip_type_name , t.trip_number , t.trip_date , guide_name , t.trip_capacity
ORDER BY d.destination_name , tt.trip_type_name , t.trip_date , t.trip_number;
```

[image: ERD]

OK so I have figured out the JOINs I am now struggling with concatenating the GUIDE NAME, it shows up as the number 0(zero).  I have the same issue with another table that needs to show the guest name from  a concatenated first and last name that corresponds to an id and trip number.

here is my code:

```
use www;
SELECT 
d.destination_name,
tt.trip_type_name,
t.trip_number,
t.trip_date,
t.trip_capacity,
CONCAT(e.nick_name+' '+e.last_name AS guide_name
COUNT(r.guest_id) AS guests_booked,
(t.trip_capacity - COUNT(r.guest_id)) AS positions_available
FROM
trip_type tt
    JOIN
trips t ON tt.trip_type_code = t.trip_type_code
    JOIN
destination d ON t.destination_code = d.destination_code
    JOIN
reservation r ON t.trip_number = r.trip_number
GROUP BY trip_number;

Second SQL query 

use www;
SELECT 
d.destination_name,
tt.trip_type_name,
t.trip_number,
t.trip_date,
CONCAT(e.last_name + ', ' + e.first_name) AS guide_name,
CONCAT(g.last_name + ', ' + g.first_name) AS guest_name,
ex.exp_name AS guest_experience,
g.age AS guest_age,
g.weight AS guest_weight,
g.swimmer AS guest_is_swimmer,
g.mobile_phone AS guest_mobile_phone
FROM
trip_type tt
    JOIN
trips t ON tt.trip_type_code = t.trip_type_code
    JOIN
destination d ON t.destination_code = d.destination_code
    JOIN
reservation r ON t.trip_number = r.trip_number
    JOIN
guests g ON r.guest_id = g.guest_id
    JOIN
experience ex ON ex.exp_code = g.exp_code
    JOIN
employees e ON t.guide_employee_id = e.employee_id
ORDER BY d.destination_name , tt.trip_type_name , t.trip_date , g.last_name , e.employee_id
```

Comment: You are not joining the tables either implicitly or explicitly so you are actually getting a cross join of every table.  read up on sql joins and use the diagram to figure out your relationships http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Comment: in addition my comment about you having cross joins also meas you are not getting the correct numbers you desire.

Comment: It's best if you ask the second part as a separate question - we like to keep our questions on SO very focused. This way, you can accept the existing answer as solving your first problem. Plus you'll get more attention on your second question that way. Welcome to SO :)

Comment: Thanks Jeff - Ive asked a new question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38946986/concatenting-first-and-last-name-while-joining-to-another-table-with-an-id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need condition on relation otherwise you obtain  a cartesian product between the tables .

```
SELECT 
    d.destination_name,
    tt.trip_type_name,
    t.trip_number,
    t.trip_date,
    (e.first_name + e.last_name) AS guide_name,
    t.trip_capacity,
    COUNT(r.guest_id) AS guests_booked,
    (COUNT(r.guest_id)-t.trip_capacity) AS positions_available
FROM trips t
inner join  employees e on e.employee_id = t.employee_employee_id
inner join  destination d on d.destination_code = t.destination_code
inner join  trip_type tt  on tt.trip_type_cde = t.trip_type_cde
inner join   reservation r on r.trip_number = t.reservation_trip_number 
GROUP BY d.destination_name , tt.trip_type_name , t.trip_number , t.trip_date , guide_name , t.trip_capacity
ORDER BY d.destination_name , tt.trip_type_name , t.trip_date , t.trip_number;
```

Comment: @JamalKendrick   . change the question code  .. is not fair .. you have ha problem  wiith the corretct use of join and i have proposed a solution .. if my solution for you orginal question is right you should rate my answer as accetpted  .. and post the second  question in a  new post . properly documented .