# Concatenting first and last name while Joining to another table with an ID

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to solve an issue with joining last and first names that are identified using id's in another table.  My code is producing the correct fields, but the Guide_Name and Guest_Name columns show all/only 0 (zero).  Here is my code:

```
use www;
SELECT 
    d.destination_name,
    tt.trip_type_name,
    t.trip_number,
    t.trip_date,
    CONCAT(e.last_name + ', ' + e.first_name) AS guide_name,
    CONCAT(g.last_name + ', ' + g.first_name) AS guest_name,
    ex.exp_name AS guest_experience,
    g.age AS guest_age,
    g.weight AS guest_weight,
    g.swimmer AS guest_is_swimmer,
    g.mobile_phone AS guest_mobile_phone
FROM
    trip_type tt
        JOIN
    trips t ON tt.trip_type_code = t.trip_type_code
        JOIN
    destination d ON t.destination_code = d.destination_code
        JOIN
    reservation r ON t.trip_number = r.trip_number
        JOIN
    guests g ON r.guest_id = g.guest_id
        JOIN
    experience ex ON ex.exp_code = g.exp_code
        JOIN
    employees e ON t.guide_employee_id = e.employee_id
ORDER BY d.destination_name , tt.trip_type_name , t.trip_date , g.last_name , e.employee_id
```

And here is the EER diagram:

[image: And here is the EER diagram:]

Comment: Thanks, HiDeo, how do i edit correctly when i post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CONCAT should just be a comma separated list of strings, so I would first change

```
CONCAT(e.last_name + ', ' + e.first_name)
```

to

```
CONCAT(e.last_name, ', ', e.first_name)
```

and see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

With + in the concat, mysql thinks you want them treated as numbers. Perhaps you're confusing it with javascript?

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_concat

Answer (score 0):

dave has the heart of this problem, but I expect you also will want to deal with nulls.  I think the final code you want will look like this:

```
COALESCE(CONCAT(e.last_name,', ',e.first_name),e.last_name,e.first_name,'') AS guide_name,
COALESCE(CONCAT(g.last_name,', ',g.first_name),g.last_name,g.first_name,'') AS guest_name,
```

Comment: the field is marked as NOT NULL in the SCHEMA, will this make a difference?

Comment: @JamalKendrick -- probably not, I expect at some point you will change to left joins for guest or guide table and then they will be null.

Comment: How do I correctly format my SQL so that is not just a long blob of code?

Comment: @JamalKendrick - indent it 4 characters.  There is a formatting help link right there (points)